# How do I create multiple versioned APIs under a single domain with Zappa?

Tags: flask, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, zappa

I'm written a number of services that live under a single domain and are deployed with Zappa. Now, I need to make a breaking change to one of the services so I'd like to version it.

API Gateway doesn't allow me to include a version in the base path that points to the new lambda function.

I currently have this working:

```
STAGE-api.DOMAIN.TLD/service_name1
STAGE-api.DOMAIN.TLD/service_name2
STAGE-api.DOMAIN.TLD/service_name3
```

I'd like to use the following pattern:

```
STAGE-api.DOMAIN.TLD/service_name1/version
STAGE-api.DOMAIN.TLD/service_name2/version
STAGE-api.DOMAIN.TLD/service_name3/version
```

The problem I'm running into is when I try to configure the API Gateway mapping. Each service_nameX is configured as the base path and points to the appropriate lambda function. What I want to do is set the base path to service_name1/version and point it to the new lambda function.